# is there any way to transfer file in Ascii mode using ftp or sftp

Tags: linux, sftp, ftp, ascii

We have a server and we need to transfer file in Ascii mode.

While transferring : when we use "ftp" command getting below error

```
Error: 530 Log on attempt by user rejected  (530 Secure connection required)

or 

Error: 530 Not logged in. Username/password incorrect, user disabled, or user logged in too many times
```

Password is correct as i am able to login using sftp but in sftp not sure how to transfer in ascii mode. Any suggestion pls

Pls suggest if there is any reference link to refer

Answer (score 4):

**1. FTP**

Your FTP Server requires connections to be made in secure mode. This extension must also be supported by your FTP client, and I suspect that this is the issue here. (You don't say what command line `ftp` client you're using, so I can't confirm it.)

**2. SFTP**

There's no concept of "ASCII mode" when transferring with most implementations of protocols such as SFTP. As is noted by the [SFTP Standards specification](https://www.sftp.net/specification), most implementations are at SFTP v3, but ASCII transfer mode wasn't defined until SFTP v4.

**Notes**

Typically the problem is with line endings between Mac, Windows, and UNIX/Linux. In such cases the `dos2unix` command or its converse `unix2dos` can be used after the transfer to fix up the file. For more complex conversions it may be possible to use `iconv`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ..Thanks Martin. Could you please help me with any reference links to refer the syntax of Ascii pls

Comment: @Arya As I've commented before (and as the answer now says), there's no ASCII mode in OpenSSH SFTP. Are you are using other client and server? My previous comment did not really aim to help you, but to make the answer accurate. In most cases you cannot use ASCII mode in SFTP. You have to convert the file before or after the transfer.